# PyQt:How to Place Progressbar in Splash Form

Tags: controls, timer, pyqt, progress-bar, splash-screen

Guys any one can please help me in doing this -> I need to place a progress bar (QProgressbar) in a QSplashScreen . How can i do this in design?..can i really implement it?

Using pyqt3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Qt docs of Qt4.4](http://web.mit.edu/qt-dynamic/www/qsplashscreen.html):

> If you wish to do your own drawing you
>   can get a pointer to the pixmap used
>   in the splash screen with pixmap().
>   Alternatively, you can subclass
>   QSplashScreen and reimplement
>   drawContents().

I suppose this would also work in Qt 3 (or PyQt3); just subclass QSplashScreen and re-implement drawContents() by putting a progress bar on it, and extending the interface with some progress methods.

If you look at the changes between Qt3 and Qt4 you can see how the Trolltech people did that (albeit in C++).